# Will Ubuntu 14.04 offer direct upgrade from 13.04

Tags: 13.04, upgrade

Will Ubuntu 14.04 offer a direct upgrade from 13.04?
Ubuntu Desktop the main interest here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two supported upgrade paths:

1. From one stable version to the very next (including LTS), so you could upgrade 13.04 -> 13.10 -> 14.04.
2. From one LTS to the next (12.04 to 14.04).

With the exception of case #2, upgrades that "skip" over one or more releases are not supported.