# Upgrading Lubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu

I have a copy of lubuntu (the "light" distribution of ubuntu) on one of my machines.  I received a message that the version that I have is no longer supported and that I must upgrade.  When I pressed okay to start upgrading the message box mentioned referenced a newer version of Ubuntu. I was surprised that this did not mention a that there was a new version of Lubuntu.  I decided to press okay and see what happens.  Nothing happened.  The software would not upgrade to either Lubuntu or Ubuntu.

Question:
How do I upgrade Lubuntu?  Or am I stuck having to reinstall for each new version?

Comment: What version of Lubuntu are you trying to upgrade?

Comment: @Mitch: Trying to check for duplicates, a found two incompatible answers: here http://askubuntu.com/questions/368068/how-will-people-upgrade-from-12-10-to-later-releases-after-13-04-is-eol seems that there will be an upgrade  from intermediate releases to 14.04, and here http://askubuntu.com/questions/414521/will-ubuntu-14-04-offer-direct-upgrade-from-13-04 it is stated that no, there will be none. So one of the two is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu is different from Ubuntu (although the guts of the two distros are similar).  Lubuntu 12.04 and 13.04 have reached End Of Life.  Lubuntu 12.10 dies next month so the only version that will be supported in a couple of days is Lubuntu 13.10 and the new release 14.04 (next month).  To update a version you must either update in order 12.04 to 12.10 to 13.04 to 13.10 etc, which is time consuming  and apt to cause errors or update from one LTS to the next.  Unfortunately, the new LTS release of Lubuntu 14.04 is the first Lubuntu LTS so you are out of luck there.
To see the new available versions you must go to Menu->Preferences->Software & Updates.  Navigate to Updates tab and choose your options and then close the window.  You will then be notified of all new versions if that is your choice.
In your case you probably need to back up your data, download the new ISO (14.04) when it is released and do a fresh install.  Do not forget to do an MD5Sum on the ISO after you download it.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM