# Upgrade failed for the Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: xorg

I upgrade Ubuntu from 13.04 to 14.04,and my notebook now does not accept the upgrade and keep getting this message :

```
The system running in low - graphics mode.Your screen,graphics card,and input device settings could not be detected correctly.You will need to configure these yourself
```

And when i click `ok` it takes me into a white board and can not write anything.My question is,what can i do to return back to 13.04 version?

Comment: There is an answer here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/414521/will-ubuntu-14-04-offer-direct-upgrade-from-13-04

Comment: Why you think rolling back will help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade 14.04 directly from 13.04.

First you upgrade into 13.10 then upgrade to 14.04 LTS.